# HTML Canvas Email Button from scratch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am working with HTML Canvas and i need to create this email button: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ymuvk.png.

I was starting to create a cornered rectangle first, but i spent 2 hours and i didn't get enywhere. I was searching on blogs, Youtube, websites for tutorials and examples but i didn't find anything realy usefull for this button.

Here is the code i was working on:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="500px" height="500px" style="border: solid 1px silver;">
</canvas>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var canvas = $('#canvas');
        var context = canvas.get(0).getContext('2d');

        /*
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(100, 100);
        ctx.arcTo(0, 100, 0, 0, 30);
        ctx.arcTo(0, 0, 100, 0, 30);
        ctx.arcTo(100, 0, 100, 100, 30);
        ctx.arcTo(100, 100, 0, 100, 30);
        ctx.stroke();
        */

        var rectX = 100;
        var rectY = 175;
        var rectWidth = 300;
        var rectHeight = 150; //125
        var cornerRadius = 125;

        context.lineJoin = 'round';
        context.lineWidth = 4;

        context.strokeRect(rectX + (cornerRadius / 2), rectY + (cornerRadius / 2), rectWidth - cornerRadius, rectHeight - cornerRadius);
    });
</script>
```

Can anybody help me with this button or just point me to right direction in making Canvas images.

Thanks for answers!

Comment: Just curious... Why do you need to use the HTML5 canvas API? There are plenty of way to create that button...

Comment: It is a part of a school project and HTML5 canvas API is required for grading the assignment.

Comment: Learn the Canvas API commands! `How-to`: **Button outline:** lineTo+arc+lineTo+arc. **Button Fill:** context.fill with createLinearGradient from top to bottom. **Left circle:** arc with linear gradient strokeStyle & off-white fillStyle. **"Email":** fillText first with black fillStyle then fillTextAgain with white fillStyle and slight rightward offset. **Envelope icon:** drawImage an envelope icon